# Set admin email as BCC for WooCommerce cancelled and failed orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am currently using this code to send out notifications on failed and cancelled orders.

```
function wc_cancelled_order_add_customer_email( $recipient, $order )
{ 
 return $recipient . ',' . $order->billing_email; 
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_cancelled_order', 'wc_cancelled_order_add_customer_email', 10, 2 ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_failed_order', 'wc_cancelled_order_add_customer_email', 10, 2 );
```

The problem is that those two admin emails I have set in the system under woocommerce settings are also added to the email recipient together with the customers email.
Is it possible to tweak this, so the admin E-mail adresses are on BCC instead, so the customer can't see their email addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make some little changes to your hooked function and to add an additional hooked function to handle the admin email as BCC recipient:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_cancelled_order', 'custom_cancelled_and_failed_order_email_recipients', 10, 2 ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_failed_order', 'custom_cancelled_and_failed_order_email_recipients', 10, 2 );
function custom_cancelled_and_failed_order_email_recipients( $recipient, $order ) { 
    // Check that the WC_Order object always exist
    if( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) )
        $recipients = $order->get_billing_email(); 

    return $recipients;
} 


add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'custom_cancelled_and_failed_order_email_headers', 20, 3 );
function custom_cancelled_and_failed_order_email_headers( $header, $email_id, $order ) {
    // Only for 'cancelled' and 'failed' order notifications
    if( in_array( $email_id, ['cancelled_order', 'failed_order'] ) ) { 
        // Get original admin recipient
        $recipient = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Cancelled_Order']->settings['recipient'];
        // Add Admin email As Bcc recipient
        $header .= 'Bcc: ' . $recipient . "\r\n";
    }
    return $header;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.